# ofstream failing to create file when program runs with sudo

Tags: c++, linux, sudo, permission-denied, ofstream

I'm writing an application that is using libusb, and I'm working on a section that involves writing the data of the devices to an XML file.

I've realised that the program will likely need to be run with sudo, as when I tried to transfer to a device there wasn't sufficient permissions. However, when I run the program with sudo, the ofstream will no longer create the file. Why is this, and how can I fix it?

```
int writeDeviceList(const char* fileName, libusb_device **devs, ssize_t deviceCount)
{
std::ofstream file;
file.open(fileName, std::ios::trunc);

if(!file)
{
    //Code enters here when run with root
    std::cout << "\"" << fileName << "\" file failed to open\n"; 
    return -1;
}

file << "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
file << "<USB>\n";

ssize_t i;
for(i = 0; i < deviceCount; i++)
{
    if(printdev(devs[i], &file) == -1)
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
file << "</USB>\n";
file.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't suppose you checked [`std::perror()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/perror) ?

Comment: perror returned "Permission denied" @WhozCraig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason is if you are root on the local machine you run on, but the file is on an nfs mount of a remote machine, e.g. your normal user's home dir. Then root on the local machine will not be able to write or even open the file.

Comment: Okay, how would I fix it?

Comment: If you can, just put the output file somewhere where root has write access, i.e. not on the NFS mount.